# Categorias en wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

tengo el siguiente código en category.php:

```
<?php
if (in_category('6'))  {include(TEMPLATEPATH  .'/category-1.php');}//NOTICIAS
if (in_category('14')) {include(TEMPLATEPATH  .'/category-2.php');}//REGIONALES
if (in_category('CentrodeChile')) {include(TEMPLATEPATH  .'/category-3.php');}
if (in_category('Magazine')) {include(TEMPLATEPATH  .'/category-4.php');}
if (in_catergory('8')) {include('/category-1.php');}//NACIONALES
if (in_category('7'))  {include('/category-6.php');}
```

?>

Pero el problema surge con las categorias 7 y 8 no va a los archivos ahí incluídos, las otras me funcionan bien, tengo agregado con el número o el nombre de la categoria para probar, pero lamentablemente no me funciona, que estaré haciendo mal, o que me faltará?

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, lo que sucede es que en las categorías 7 y 8 no estas incluyendo los TEMPLATEPATH, es por ello que no te puede cargar los include correctamente. Tambien hay un error de texto en la categoría 8, dice:

> in_cate**r**gory

deberia decir `in_category`

Intenta reemplazar las líneas de las categorías 7 y 8 por estas:

```
if (in_category('8')) {include(TEMPLATEPATH  .'/category-1.php');}
if (in_category('7')) {include(TEMPLATEPATH  .'/category-6.php');}
```

Con esto debería esta solucionado.
Saludos

Comment: Hola, ya descubrí cual era el problema, sucede que se nombraba el archivo con el id de la categoria correspondiente, no uso el archivo sólo category.php